# Django admin, changelist_view, ModelAdmin seems to act like a singleton

Tags: django, django-admin

I noticed a strange behaviour while extending ModelAdmin.
I have this code:

```
class MakeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ...

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            self.list_display = ['company', 'name']
        # else:
        #    self.list_display = ['name']
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context,)
```

The goal is to change `list_display` dynamically based on user (supervisor or not).

I log in with two different users, in two different browsers, one of them results to be a superuser, the other isn't.

self.list_display is set by one of users but debugging the request with the other user I can see the variable still set, so it changes the next behavior of the other user's view.

Uncommenting the lines it works but I don't like it at all.
It seems to me it's acting like a singleton.

I also tried to change to:

```
 super(MakeModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context,)
```

But it has the same effect.

Is there any solution for that?

Maybe this is not the right way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_display) way to dynamically change the behavior of the admin based on the request is to use the `get_*` methods. In your case that would be something like:

```
def get_list_display(self, request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return ['company', 'name']
    else:
        return super().get_list_display(request)
```

As for `AdminSite`, it's not a singleton (that is, the same instance isn't returned every time you instantiate it). It's just that a single instance is created during the Django setup process and then used to service all subsequent requests.